# Do Eureka server and Feign Client for spring microservices integration work without internet in production environment?

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign

What are the production environment requirements for this method of integration? Does spring cloud work in WAN defined by a client/company?

Comment: Looks like there is nothing in your question about Spring Integration framework: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration. Be careful when you choose tag over here for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for an outside internet connection for eureka, feign or any of the spring cloud projects.